# What is wrong with this Ruby code 2?

Tags: ruby

What is wrong with this code?

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def greet(other_name)
    "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you asking this?  Did the code give you an error message when you ran it, or is this some kind of quiz where you have to find problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the code as

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
   "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{@name}" # <~~ you missed `@` before name.
  end
end
```

If you write only `name`(instead of `@name`), Ruby will try to look for a local var named as `name`, but you didn't define any. Then it will try to check if any method you have defined as `name` or not, that also not present. So finally you will get

```
undefined local variable or method `name'
```

---

Here is an example after the fix :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
   "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{@name}" 
  end
end

Person.new("Raju").greet('Welcome!') # => "Hi Welcome!, my name is Raju"
```